# help with regular expressions

Tags: html, regex

how can i match a text that is outside of an anchor tag ? example : `"test <a>test</a>"` i want to get the test outside of the a tags only.

thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i m trying to replace text that is only outside of a link tag.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Javascript in the browser, or are you trying to do this to raw HTML source files?

Comment: i m doing this on a string that only has text and a tags

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the example is "test<a>test</a>more<a>link2</a>still more"? (in other  words, do you need to count balanced tags? Can't do that with regexps.

Comment: all i want is replace the value "test" that is outside of the anchor tag

Answer (score 4):

You're getting into dangerous land here in the sense that trying to parse HTML/XML  with regular expressions is not feasible in most cases. Is parsing the markup not an option?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a look-ahead regex. These can be quite complex. See this page for more info about this topic: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

For your simple example, something like this would do the trick:

```
/test(?=<a>test<\/a>)/
```

However, it will get very *very* complex if you need to match against more varied HTML, to the point that it may be virtually impossible to get right if you don't know how the input HTML will be formatted.

You may therefore find it better in the long run to use a DOM parser to locate text in an HTML document.